# How to convert integer number to fixed point in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am writing the code with VHDL language. I have to convert integer number to fixed point. Can anyone help me? Are there any rules for it?

Comment: What did you try so far and what problem did you encounter?

Comment: Hint : a fixed point number has an integer part and a fractional part. What do you know about the fractional part of your input?

Comment: my input is file with .txt index